How to copy requirements.txt and setup.py files into docker image from parent folder
Here is the directory structure of my project:Directory tree
From the backend folder, I want to create a Docker image that loads the setup.py and requirements.txt files which are in the parent folder. Additionally, I want to load the src/ folder which is also in the parent folder. Here is the content of setup.py: https://github.com/ahmedaao/design-autonomous-car/blob/master/setup.py
and here is the content of fastapi_app.py: https://github.com/ahmedaao/design-autonomous-car/blob/master/backend_app.py
Here is Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.10.12

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./fastapi_app.py /app/
COPY ./../requirements.txt /app/
COPY ./../src/ /app/src
COPY ./../setup.py /app/

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["uvicorn", "fastapi_app:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]

When I try to build the image with: sudo docker build -t test .
I have this output: Output from docker build
Maybe you can help to solve this problem. Thanks
You can view the Dockerfile I tested above.

Your docker build command is run from the backend/ directory. It might make more sense to run it from the project root.
If your project is structured like this (from your screenshot):
├── backend
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── fastapi_app.py
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    └── metrics.py

Then perhaps it might make more sense to formulate your Dockerfile like this:
FROM python:3.10.12

WORKDIR /app

COPY backend/fastapi_app.py /app/
COPY requirements.txt /app/
COPY src/ /app/src
COPY setup.py /app/

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["uvicorn", "fastapi_app:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]

You would then build the image from the project root:
docker build -f backend/Dockerfile -t test .

This would be a good approach if you are going to have multiple Dockerfile in the project (perhaps you will have a frontend/Dockerfile as well?).
Alternatively, if there will just be a single image, you could move the Dockerfile to the project root and then your build command would simplify to:
docker build -t test .

Either approach will get you around the problem of trying to copy files from outside of the build context.
Update
In response to question in comments and looking at https://github.com/ahmedaao/design-autonomous-car.
You can reduce the size of the image by adding a specific requirements.txt into the backend/ folder. Something like this should do it:
uvicorn==0.29.0
numpy==1.26.4
fastapi==0.110.1
pillow==10.2.0
python-dotenv==1.0.1
tensorflow==2.15.0.post1

Then update your Dockerfile with:
COPY backend/requirements.txt /app/

The resulting image would then be around 2.67 GB. Unfortunately it's the tensorflow package that's bloating the image. Without that the size drops to 1.11 GB.

It works. Thank you. One small detail, I have limited the files and folders present in the tree structure above to simplify the problem. However, at the root of the project, there are other folders and files. I wanted to know if these were also sent to the Docker image because the created image weighs almost 3Gb which seems huge to me. Thank you for the feedback.

The COPY commands in the Dockerfile determine what will be copied onto the image. If the files and folders you mention match one of the COPY commands then they will bloat the image. Perhaps you could amend your question with some information on the layout of your project and an indication of those file/folder paths.

Here is the repo of my project: https://github.com/ahmedaao/design-autonomous-car. I think the problem comes from requirements.txt file. In my case, I only need some packets from requirements.txt to create my image (see the imports from backend/fastapi_app.py) but here all packets are copy into the docker image. Is it possible to limit the packet to copy ?

I see. You are saying that your backend image doesn't need all of the packages listed in the requirements.txt in the root folder. Yes, that makes sense. I'd suggest that you create a separate requirements.txt file in the backend/ folder that only contains the packages required for that service. Looking at the import statements in backend/fastapi_app.py I agree that only a subset of the packages appear to be necessary. See the update at the end of my answer.

Here's the working example
Project structure
.
├── backend
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── fastapi_app.py
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    └── metrics.py

Dockerfile
FROM python:3.10.12

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["uvicorn", "backend.fastapi_app:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]

Build & Run

FYI: If you intend to build & run from inside the backend
directory. Then you should build with the command  bash docker build -f Dockerfile -t fastapi_test_v2 ../  everything remains the
same!

# Build the app: From the project root
docker build -f backend/Dockerfile -t fastapi_test .

# Build the app: from backend dir
bash docker build -f Dockerfile -t fastapi_test_v2 ../

# Run the container: 
docker run -it -p 8000:8000 fastapi_test

Test out
$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8000       
{"status":"OK","message":"Pong"}

Notes

Make sure to build the image from the project root
Set the correct Flask App reference in Dockerfile in the CMD. For my case, backend.fastapi_app:app
Run the container by mapping the host vs container port. In my case, I have used -p 8000:8000

I hope this helps!
